# How to be able to scroll an overlayed div inside a flex box (CSS)?

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, overlay

I have an application layout with 2 nav bars and a content are with 3 main sections, a left panel, a main panel and a right panel. The easiest way I have found for the panels is to use a flex box. However, in the left panel I have a stepped workflow which has a the steps overlayed on top of the progress bar. The problem is if you make the browser too small the overflow kicks in, a scrollbar appears but the progress bar does not scroll. Please help!

Here is the jsfiddle...   https://jsfiddle.net/dpkxzgv9/1/

HTML:

```
    <div class='ngcds-container'>
    <div class='ngcds-navbar'>Primary navigation bar</div>

  <div class='ngcds-secondary-navbar'>Secondary navigation bar</div>

    <div class='ngcds-body ngcds-body-top'>
        <div class='ngcds-content'>
      <div class='ngcds-left-panel workflow-side-panel'>
        <div id='divWorkflowBar' class='workflow-bar'>
          <div id='divWorkflowBarProgress' class='workflow-bar-progress' style='height: 50%'>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id='workflow-items' class='workflow-items'>
          <div class='workflow-item'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle done'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle done'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text done'>Step 1</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class='workflow-item'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle done'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle done'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text done'>Step 2</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class='workflow-item'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle done'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle done'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text done'>Step 3</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class='workflow-item selected'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle selected'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle selected'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text selected'>Step 4</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class='workflow-item'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text'>Step 5</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class='workflow-item'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text'>Step 6</div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class='workflow-item'>
            <div id='divWorkflowCircle' class='workflow-circle'>
              <div id='divWorkflowInnerCircle' class='workflow-inner-circle'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='divWorkflowText' class='workflow-text'>Step 7</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='ngcds-main-panel'>
        main panel
      </div>

      <div class='ngcds-right-panel'>
        right side panel
      </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 600px;
}

.ngcds-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.ngcds-body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.ngcds-body-top {
    top: 110px;
}

.ngcds-navbar {
    background-color: #276193;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 2;
}

.ngcds-secondary-navbar {
    background-color: #068CC1;
    color: white;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ngcds-content {
  display: flex;
    flex: auto;
}

.ngcds-left-panel {
  order: 1;
  background: #3E4B52;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.ngcds-main-panel {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
  font-size: 24px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.ngcds-right-panel {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #3E4B52;
  color: white;
  order: 3;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.workflow-side-panel {
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.workflow-bar
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 63px;
    background: #4D595F;
    height: calc(100% - 126px);
    width: 20px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 31px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.workflow-bar-progress
{
  position: relative;
    background: #068CC1;
    width: #068CC1;
}

.workflow-items {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.workflow-item {
    width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
    cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 10px solid #3E4B52;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.workflow-item.selected {
    border-right: 10px solid #068CC1;
}

.workflow-item:first-child {
    margin-top: 31px;
}

.workflow-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 31px;
}

.workflow-circle {
    float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: #4D595F;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.workflow-circle.done
{
    background: #068CC1;
    border: 1px solid #6B9EB6;
}

.workflow-circle.selected
{
    background: #068CC1;
    border: 1px solid #9ADDF7;
  opacity: 1.00;
}

.workflow-inner-circle {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 11px 0px 0px 11px;
  background-color: #697277;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.workflow-inner-circle.done {
  background-color: #9ADDF7;
  opacity: 0.70;
}

.workflow-inner-circle.selected {
  background-color: #9ADDF7;
  opacity: 1.00;
}

.workflow-text {
  float: left;
  height: 66px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  line-height: 66px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 0.80;
}

.workflow-text.done {
  font-weight: normal;
  opacity: 1.00;
}

.workflow-text.selected {
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 1.00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `ngcds-left-panel workflow-side-panel` div.
It should work as expected.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dpkxzgv9/2/)

Comment: Thanks Nandita! That solved the problem but I just noticed a new one...look at the grey bar. It resizes to visible area no the 'scrollable' area.

Comment: Sorry I tried but cant seem to find a solution. May be someone else can point out whats wrong or how to fix it

Comment: Thanks so much Nandita! I figured it out! Add a @media (since I know what size I want to start the scroll with and what the size of the bar should be at that time)...updated fiddle .. https://jsfiddle.net/dpkxzgv9/3/